# What is the name of this bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

I found this bug in my garden in India this morning. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a tortoise beetle (Family Chrysomelidae (Leaf beetle), subfamily Cassidinae). It looks very much like the Indian Green Tortoise Beetle *Chiridopsis bipunctata*. https://indiabiodiversity.org/observation/show/338651 
I am almost sure it is in the genus Chiridopsis.